# Can I save styles in the dev tools temporary?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

When *„dev-tooling“* around, usually thy mighty chrome browser will throw out the changes after e. g. a page reload. There are plugins to directly save them to a file, which can be nice but for experiments or small tests that's not always a great solution.

So my question is: Is it possible to just temporary save e. g. styles for the session while you have the dev-tools opened and make *n* reloads without loosing the dom manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can persist your style changes using [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en) instead of relying on plugins. In terms of temporary sessions, this doesn't seem to be possible. DevTools has a History tab for Local Modifications, allowing you to revert changes like Styles. However, when used in combination with Workspaces, it doesn't apply. The difference is that Local Modifications are stored in a memory stack structure, but when you configure a Workspace, it has a direct binding with the file itself.

Something you could try as a workaround is to have your text editor configured to not automatically reload changes it detects (a setting somewhere?). Have your CSS file opened in the background and avoid navigating to the text editor until you finished your session. When you do navigate to it, it may prompt you to reload changes. If you cancel that and then do a save, it should overwrite the changes that were previously made from within DevTools.